# While downloading a C# application from my website, the prerequisite or supporting application does not get downloaded?

Tags: windows-installer, setup-project, setup-deployment, temporary-files, prerequisites

I have a C# application deployed on my IIS server in WIn 7. I had also included a preRequisite EXE along with the set up project of my target application.
 But when I download this target application from my website only the target application EXE gets downloaded and preRequisite application's EXE does not get downloaded.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0):

For that you need to select the second options from the image below :

[image]